# How to connect to local host using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I installed MySql on my own machine. I created database, create table, ... using MySql CommandLine Client. When working on a project in school, I connected to school's database using this syntax:

```
public static Statement connect() {
  try {
   Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ).newInstance();
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "1", "2", "3" );
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
  }
  catch( Exception e ) {
   System.out.println( "Connection Error:  " + e );
  }
  return stmt;
 }
```

In my local machine, I don't have to type in user name, all I did is just login with my password as root user:

```
Enter password: ****
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.1.53-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use chandb;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_chandb |
+------------------+
| another          |
| cars             |
| employees        |
+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from Another;
+----+-----------+----------+
| Id | GoldValue | Model    |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  0 |       100 | Civic DX |
+----+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I would like to know how can I connect to my local machine's database? what should I put as parameters within method .getConnection

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection( 
   "1", // ?
   "2", // ?
   "3"  ); // ?
```

Best regards,
Chan

Comment: Dude, remove that username and password from your code snippet, ASAP! Remove the hostname too, while you're at it. Also you don't need to clutter the snippet with the mistyped `show tables` bit

Comment: Thanks for reminding about security issue. Editted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Simple Connection:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

    String serverName = "localhost";
    String mydatabase = "mydatabase";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase; 

    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, but it did not work. I got exception thrown in main. Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql :// localhost/chandb
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at Program.main(Program.java:15)

Comment: There are spaces in the URL which makes it invalid. Remove it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you left your username and password *in* the source you posted.

I don't see why you can't just do

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/chandb", "user, "pass");
```