# Java derby database not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Is there any issue with these lines of code? All I get is "invalid entry".
I have a database called production with a table called PRODUCTION.

```
try {
    String mk = jTextField1.getText();
    String mn = jTextField2.getText();
    String ab = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    String bc = (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:1527/production");
        {
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:1527/production";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "connection success");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            String query = "update PRODUCT set FACTORY='" + ab + "' PRODUCT_NAME = '" + mk + "' UNIT= '" + bc + "' and OPENING_BALANCE'" + mn + "');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record has been inserted");
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "invalid entry");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in Connectivity", "Message", 2);
}
```

Comment: OT: your first try.... what is that for?

Comment: its for adding an item to an inventory system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4436173/873433

Comment: You should log exceptions (or use `e.printStackTrace()`), not only post feedback messages like `invalid entry` that do not provide detailed information to analyse the problem.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel i will try to avoid it at all times

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not correct :

1. You have to use `,` between the fields
2. You don't need to use and when you set the fields (`and OPENING_BALANCE'" + mn + "'`)
3. In the end of your query there are a closed parenthesis `)` that you don't need it

But your way is open to sytax error and SQL Inection you have to use PreparedStatement instead, it is more secure and more helpful :

```
query = "update PRODUCT set FACTORY = ?, PRODUCT_NAME = ?, UNIT= ?, OPENING_BALANCE = ?";
try (PreparedStatement update = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

    update.setString(1, ab);
    update.setString(2, mk);
    update.setString(3, bc);
    update.setString(4, mn);

    update.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, i have edited the code but in this line,try (PreparedStatement update = connection.prepareStatement(query)), there is a slight error as it sayscannot find the variable connection, what could be the problem

Comment: @Stevoski connection in your case is `con` got it?